# Disable Norton 360 in Windows XP

Tags: services, norton-360

Since Norton is taking up 98% CPU time, I need it disabled for a customer. I don't want to uninstall it since they have a 2 year subscription (Don't worry, I'll smack them later), but I want to disable it from starting up. When I go through MSCONFIG and remove the service, I get Access Denied. When I go to SERVICES.MSC and disable it, I get Access Denied. Same effects if I start in Safe Mode. So how can I disable Norton without uninstalling it, in case the customer wants to use it?

PS - The issue is that his computer is extremely slow after starting up. No viruses detected, RAM is good, and HDD has no bad blocks. In Task Manager, I see the 98% CPU Time for the ccApp process.

Comment: Who down voted and didn't give a reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Norton forums](http://community.norton.com/t5/Norton-360/How-do-I-manually-shut-down-Norton-360/td-p/61115):

> If you want to manually shut down Norton 360 completely, you may need
>   to get into Settings of Norton 360 and disable each protection
>   individually.
>
> 1. Under Quick Controls, uncheck Identity Safe and Phishing Protection.
> 2. Click Virus & Spyware Protection. Under Automatic Protection Settings tab, uncheck Turn on Auto-Protect, Turn on SONAR, Turn on
>      Suspecious Activity Monitoring, and Turn on Email check.
> 3. Click Firewall Protection. Under General Settings tab, uncheck Turn on Firewall and Turn on Browser Protection. Under Intrusion Prevntion
>      tab, uncheck Turn on Intrusion Prevention.
> 4. If you have Add-on pack installed, click Norton Add-on pack in Settings. Uncheck Privacy Control, Parental Control and AntiSpam.
>      Click Done.

It's dated 2009, so things may be a little different in your version, but I think the gist is there - disable each service individually.

Tell them the only way to stop *all* bits and pieces from loading is to uninstall it.  They can always reinstall it later if they want. :)

Comment: I will try this tomorrow at work, and upvote and mark if it works for my version. Thanks

Comment: It jumped from 99-98% down to 95% by disabling every last detail... I'll uninstall it, and let them know that was their slowdown. I wish Norton would let you actually control it a bit better though

Comment: Uninstalled. Customer says they're gonna try for a refund